# what is the easiest way too clean adhesive residue from glass?

Tags: cleaning

Stickers have left residue on some windows and old glass jars. I have typically used acetone to clean the residue but is there a better / easier way?

Comment: Similar question: [How do I get leftover tape stickiness off of plastic surfaces?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-do-i-get-leftover-tape-stickiness-off-of-plastic-surfaces?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Orange oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_oil) (limonene) based cleaners dissolve sticker residue as well or better than acetone. Put some on, let it sit a bit, scrub a little with nylon,and wash off. There are [zillions of different brands of the stuff](https://www.google.com/search?q=Orange%20oil%20cleaner&num=20&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Ne1&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Qp74UPytK-eS2AXfpYHIDg&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAA&biw=1176&bih=789).

Answer (score 2):

There are extremely effective window scraping devices, which ensure that you always maintain the correct blade angle and dont scratch the glass pane.

also you can spray some simple window cleaner onto the glass while scraping.

[image]

Comment: When using this device, to maintain proper blade angle should both sides (the blade and handle) be in contact with the glass?

Comment: I think what you propose may be useful, but I think the slight variations between angle when its in your grip is not too bad, more important is that the blade face is completely on the glass. (i.e dont scrape with one side of the blade only.

Answer (score 1):

Use a new razor blade on the windows to scrape it off (blades like the kind you use in a extractable utility knife).  Angle the blade at about 30 degrees up from laying flat against the glass and move in a scraping (rather than slicing) motion - works great with paint too.  The old glass jars will be more difficult because of their shape... I'd try putting them in a dish washer or possibly using Sherwin Williams 'Oops' product - Lowes sells the same thing labeled as 'Goof-Off'. You might also use the 'Oops' product to keep your razor blade clean when working on the windows.

Answer (score 1):

Goof-off works wonders and won't cause any discoloration with the glass. Try to breathe as little of the vapors as you can as the smell is pretty potent.

Comment: +1 On Goof-Off or Goo-Gone or any of the similar acetone based products.  If you don't have this handy then even simple nail polish remover (primarily acetone) will do the trick.  This works better than any other method mentioned.

Comment: Rather than trying to avoid breathing it, I think the correct disclaimer is, "use in well ventilated area"

Answer (score 0):

WD-40 works well if used with caution. Be careful of overspray or spray on a paper towel or fine steelwool and wipe on the glass. Then use regular glass cleaner to remove the WD-40.

Answer (score -1):

Magic sponge and elbow grease has worked wonders on set-on sealant overspray on house windows.